# Meteor: Displaying Categories from a List

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to Meteor JS and have what I believe is a simple question.

I have a list of items each of which is assigned a category.  For example:

```
{Item: "Jump Rope", Category:  "Toys"},
{Item: "Apple",     Category:  "Food"},
{Item: "Pear",      Category:  "Food"}
```

Etc.

In the sidebar, I want to list the categories.  I thought I had found a method of how to do this, but what ends up happening is that each category is listed the number of times that it is used.

For instance, in the above example Food would be listed twice whereas Toys would be listed once.  If I were to add another Food Category item (such as Tomatoes), then Food would be listed Three times in the sidebar.  If I were to add a second Toy item then Toys would be listed twice.

This is not what I want.  What I want is for each category to be listed once in the sidebar regardless of how many items there are.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you're currently using to generate the category list?

Comment: Right now I'm using {{#each categories}} {{>category }} {{/each}}.  That is why I am getting duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) the items and them do a [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) and a [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) on the results. Assuming you have an `Items` collection that contains documents which look like `{item: String, category: String}`, you could use the following helper:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  categories: function() {
    return _.uniq(_.pluck(Items.find().fetch(), 'category'));
  }
});
```

Then your template could look something like:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each category in categories}}
    <div>{{category}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct way to achieve this.  However, I aim curious as to what the rule is with underscore.  I thought if you were going to use two or more methods, you had to use the _.chain and .val methods... or does it not matter if you are going to use the _. and next them?

Comment: In the code above, I simply passed the result of `pluck` into the call in `uniq` - nothing special there. Underscore provides `chain` as an alternative syntax for situations like this. The same could have been written: `_.chain(Items.find().fetch()).pluck('category').uniq().value();`.

Comment: This worked great -- thanks.  One last problem, though.  If a category is left blank for an item then in the sidebar there is a 'blank' category listed (i.e., an empty space that takes up a whole line).  Any idea how to remove that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  I modified the code as follows:

    {{#each category in categories}}
         {{# if this }}
              <div>{{category}}</div>
         {{/if}}
    {{/each}}

Comment: I'd recommend altering the code to look like `return _.uniq(_.compact(_.pluck(`. Using `_.compact` will remove all of the falsy values which should fix the case where the categories are undefined.

Comment: To David Weldon:  Thanks.  I followed your advice and it worked just as I needed it to.